# Module not found: Can't resolve '../xlsx' in '\node_modules\react-data-export\node_modules\tempa-xlsx'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

./node_modules/react-data-export/node_modules/tempa-xlsx/ods.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../xlsx' in 'C:\Users\Rakesh Chittimela\Documents\Rakesh Documents\Clu\clu_web\node_modules\react-data-export\node_modules\tempa-xlsx'

I Have tried Uninstalling and reinstalling node_modueles and cache clean, but no use